# Can asymmetry in the dependent variable of a regression be handled by separate MSE?

Tags: regression, distributions, standard-error

Consider the regression

$$
Y_t\sim X_t
$$

Suppose there is reason to believe that $Y_t$ varies asymmetrically, that is, the increases in positive values of $Y_t$ for a given change in $X_t$ is slower than the decreases in negative values of $Y_t$.

I use linear regression model. When I make a prediction $\text{E}[Y_t]$, I want make the distribution of positive and negative values of $Y_t$ to be symmetric. Would a possible method be

1. Calculate the positive and negative $MSE$.
   $$
   MSE_{+} = MSE\text{ of } Y_t \text{ where fitted } Y_t \ge 0 \\
   MSE_{-} = MSE\text{ of } Y_t \text{ where fitted } Y_t < 0
   $$
2. Use $\text{E}_2[Y_t]$ for my prediction defined as
   $$
   \text{E}_2[Y_t]=\begin{cases}\text{E}[Y_t]/MSE_{+}\text{ if }\text{E}[Y_t]\ge0\\
   \text{E}[Y_t]/MSE_{-}\text{ if }\text{E}[Y_t]<0
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Would this be a valid method.

I can NOT move away from the linear regression model to nonlinear regression as there're very good results from the current set up.

Also, I'm only a bachelors in math so I do not know of any standardized techniques to resolve this. In fact, a cursory search shows no industry established method.

Sincerely Yours,
Donny

Comment: You describe a non-linear model in your first paragraph and then say you specifically do not want a non-linear model. Can you explain the apparent contradiction?

Comment: I am not equiped with graduate level statistics to know what exactly non-linearity entails. If what I am asking is non-linearity, then my assumptions need to be change. Essentially, I still want to maintain my linear model, and through the use of empirical methods and hand-waving arguments, turn the distribution of the predictive series into a symmetric one. If by so doing ruins a fundamental law in statistics, then I'll forget the problem. Put differently, I'm looking for a quick fix solution but still maintain passable rigor.